# How controller loads the layout in magento 2

Tags: layout, controller, frontend, magento2

I have developed a sample module in magento 2 that just prints the hellow world.there is only one controller and one layout file

controller

```
  <?php
namespace MageClass\First\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

 public function execute()
 {
   $this->_view->loadLayout();
   $this->_view->renderLayout();
 }
}
```

layout file

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">        
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block 
            template="helloworld.phtml" 
            class="Akhil\Test\Block\Helloworld" 
            name="helloworld_test_helloworld">
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Here my doubt is how this layout and controller is linked .when i accessed controller through browser by default this layout is loading. How it's linking layout and controller.

and i want to add another layout and controller in my module.so how to link these as when accessed the controller load the required layout

Comment: whats your layout file name here ?

Comment: controller file name and folder path app/code/MageClass/First/Controller/Test/Helloworld.php

Comment: i am takling about your layout file name which is xml , like hello_world_test.xml. so same whats your file name ?

Comment: oh..i am sry Manthan..controller file name and folder path app/code/MageClass/First/Controller/Test/Helloworld.php ... Layout filename and folderpath  app/code/MageClass/First/View/forntend/layout/helloworld_test_helloworld.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Magento 2 Controller and layout file linked together with their
>   naming conventions.

So here you have created your controller file which is : **app/code/MageClass/First/Controller/Test/Helloworld.php**

Your layout file name is :
 **app/code/MageClass/First/View/forntend/layout/helloworld_tes‌​t_helloworld.xml**

> Layout file name always depends on the controller name and its action
>   name.

Naming convention of layout file is - **modulename_controllername_actionname.xml**

> Example 1:

Here your module name is "**Helloworld**" controller name is "**Test**" and your action name is "**Helloworld**".

so your layout file name should be - **helloworld_test_helloworld.xml(modulename_controllername_actionname.xml)**

Same thing now if you want to create new controller and new layout then again you need to like that using above conventions

> Example :2

Here i am creating second controller "**Test1**" and action "**Helloworld1**".

so your controller path should be - **app/code/MageClass/First/Controller/Test1/Helloworld1.php**

so here your layout file name should be - **helloworld_test1_helloworld1.xml(modulename_controllername_actionname.xml)**

More reference refer this link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html

Comment: Correction : filename should be `routeFrontName_controllerName_actionName.xml`  and not `moduleName_controllerName_actionName.xml`.